# Connectivity problems on website

Tags: domain-name-system, internet, ssl, domain-name

We've been experiencing some connectivity problems on `http://www.scirra.com`.  Running a DNS check:

```
http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=www.scirra.com
```

We're getting some errors:

> Delegation not found at parent.
>
> No delegation could be found at the parent, making your zone
>   unreachable from the Internet.
>
> Not enough nameserver information was found to test the zone
>   www.scirra.com, but an IP address lookup succeeded in spite of that.

It's been ticking by nicely for many months, and we've made no changes recently except replacing expiring SSL certificates on our servers.

Problems I'm experiencing are intermittent `This web page is not available` errors in Chrome, where refreshing sometimes loads it.

Any ideas on what could be causing these issues?

Comment: this is not a dns nor a domain name problem. You should monitor your server to check if it is overloaded, and the intermediary network equipment to see if they drop packets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue with the last hop to the server. Here are the results from a `pathping` to www.scirra.com.

```
$ pathping www.scirra.com

Tracing route to www.scirra.com [108.61.84.218]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
```

...

```
  3  vnn-rc0001-cr101-ae10-217.core.as9143.net [213.51.166.65]
  4  asd-tr0042-cr101-ae6-0.core.as9143.net [213.51.158.78]
  5  te0-6-1-4.rcr21.b031955-0.ams03.atlas.cogentco.com [149.14.34.173]
  6  be2499.ccr41.ams03.atlas.cogentco.com [130.117.1.149]
  7  be2038.rcr21.ams05.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.36.134]
  8  tinet.ams05.atlas.cogentco.com [130.117.14.50]
  9  xe-2-0-2.nyc39.ip4.gtt.net [141.136.111.106]
 10  gtt-gw.ip4.gtt.net [173.241.131.238]
 11  ae1-50g.ar1.nyc3.us.as4436.gtt.net [69.31.95.194]
 12  as20473.ae7.ar1.nyc3.us.as4436.gtt.net [69.31.34.62]
 13  108.61.244.41
 14  vl329-c11-15-b2-1-sa.pnj1.choopa.net [108.61.65.62]
 15     *     108.61.84.218

Computing statistics for 375 seconds...
            Source to Here   This Node/Link
Hop  RTT    Lost/Sent = Pct  Lost/Sent = Pct  Address
```

...

```
  3   10ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  vnn-rc0001-cr101-ae10-217.core.as9143.net [213.51.166.65]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  4   15ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  asd-tr0042-cr101-ae6-0.core.as9143.net [213.51.158.78]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  5   10ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  te0-6-1-4.rcr21.b031955-0.ams03.atlas.cogentco.com [149.14.34.173]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  6   11ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  be2499.ccr41.ams03.atlas.cogentco.com [130.117.1.149]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  7    9ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  be2038.rcr21.ams05.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.36.134]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  8    9ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  tinet.ams05.atlas.cogentco.com [130.117.14.50]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  9   84ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  xe-2-0-2.nyc39.ip4.gtt.net [141.136.111.106]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
 10   84ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  gtt-gw.ip4.gtt.net [173.241.131.238]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
 11   86ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  ae1-50g.ar1.nyc3.us.as4436.gtt.net [69.31.95.194]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
 12   89ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  as20473.ae7.ar1.nyc3.us.as4436.gtt.net [69.31.34.62]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
 13  ---     100/ 100 =100%   100/ 100 =100%  108.61.244.41
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
 14   86ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  vl329-c11-15-b2-1-sa.pnj1.choopa.net [108.61.65.62]
                               54/ 100 = 54%   |
 15   86ms    54/ 100 = 54%     0/ 100 =  0%  108.61.84.218

Trace complete.
```

**There is a 54% packet loss between hops 14 and 15.**

Comment: Excellent thank you, will pass this on to our host see if that's part of the network they are in control of.

Comment: Intermediate ping loss are not a sign of problems in the link.

Comment: @Pozzo-Balbi Huh? Can you explain that comment?

Comment: Sure, see https://forum.kimsufi.com/showthread.php/32154-80-packet-loss-decix for details. Basic idea is that an "intermediate" hop may apply rate limiting to ICMP packages, so it is dropping icmp packages intentional and not "loosing" them.

Comment: @Pozzo-Balbi OK. Possible, but unlikely.